# How to access every pixel in two images and find their absolute difference using OpenCV? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv, rgba

I have two Mat images which are BGRA (8UC4) in Android Studio. I want to be able to extract the BGRA pixel values from both images by going through each pixel one at a time and then find their absolute difference in the RGB values. I don't want to subtract transparency so I cannot use Core.absdiff(). Is there an easy way to do this? I've implemented this functionality using mat.get() and mat.put() but it's VERY slow.

I've seen the solution posted below but I am not really sure how it works or how I could change it to work with my pictures/desired functionality:

```
Mat A ;
A.convertTo(A,cvType.CV_16SC3);
int size = (int) (A.total() * A.channels());
short[] temp = new short[size];
A.get(0, 0, temp);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   temp[i] = (short) (temp[i] / 2);
C.put(0, 0, temp);
```

Most of what I have read about this involves putting the Mat data into a Java Primitive type. As I am new to both Java and OpenCV, I'm not really sure what this means?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ implementation.

```
Mat aBGRA[4];     // array of Mats to hold Blue Green Red Alpha channels
cv::split(A, aBGRA);  // split Mat A into channels
Mat bBGRA[4];
cv::split(B, bBGRA);  // split Mat B into channels
Mat cBGR[3];      // Mat array to hold absolute diff of A and B BGR channels
for ( int idx = 0; idx < 3; ++idx)   // loop BGR channels
{
    cBGR[idx] = Mat::zeros(A.rows, A.cols, CV_8U); 
    Mat diff(aBGRA[idx] != bBGRA[idx]); // create mask where A & B differ
    vector<Point> nonZero;
    cv::findNonZero(diff, nonZero); // collect list of points where A & B differ
    // for each different point in this channel
    for (auto itr = nonZero.begin(); itr != nonZero.end(); ++itr)
    {
       Point p(*itr);
       // set cBGR at point to the absolute difference between A and B at this point
       cBGR[idx].at<uint8_T>(p) = abs(aBGRA[idx].at<uint8_t>(p) - bBGRA[idx].at<uint8_t>(p)); 
    }
}
Mat C;
cv::merge(cBGR, 3, C); // merge BGR channels into C
```

Comment: My question was specific to Java as I'm using Android Studio. Would you mind explaining your code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Java. I added comments to explain code. I presume Java OpenCV has the same functionality as C++ OpenCV.